# What is the tilde (~) in the enum definition?

Tags: c#, enums, language-features, enumeration

I'm always surprised that even after using C# for all this time now, I still manage to find things I didn't know about...

I've tried searching the internet for this, but using the "~" in a search isn't working for me so well and I didn't find anything on MSDN either (not to say it isn't there)

I saw this snippet of code recently, what does the tilde(~) mean?

```
/// <summary>
/// Enumerates the ways a customer may purchase goods.
/// </summary>
[Flags]
public enum PurchaseMethod
{   
    All = ~0,
    None =  0,
    Cash =  1,
    Check =  2,
    CreditCard =  4
}
```

I was a little surprised to see it so I tried to compile it, and it worked... but I still don't know what it means/does. Any help??

Comment: This is an awesome and elegant solution allowing for smooth upgrading of the enum over time. Unfortunately it conflicts with CA-2217 and will throw an error if you use the code analysis :( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182335.aspx

Answer (score 140, accepted):

~ is the unary one's complement operator -- it flips the bits of its operand.

```
~0 = 0xFFFFFFFF = -1
```

in two's complement arithmetic, `~x == -x-1`

the ~ operator can be found in pretty much any language that borrowed syntax from C, including Objective-C/C++/C#/Java/Javascript.

Comment: That's cool. I didn't realise you could do that in an enum. Will definitely use in future

Comment: So it's the equivalent of All = Int32.MaxValue? Or UInt32.MaxValue?

Comment: All = (unsigned int)-1 == UInt32.MaxValue. Int32.MaxValue has no relevance.

Comment: I would imagine that All = Int32.MinValue?

Comment: @Stevo3000: Int32.MinValue is 0xF0000000, which is not ~0 (it's actually ~Int32.MaxValue)

Comment: @Jimmy: Int32.MinValue is 0x80000000. It has only a single bit set (not the four that F would give you).

Comment: @ILMTitan completely correct. I typed that comment out too fast.

Answer (score 60):

I'd think that:

```
[Flags]
public enum PurchaseMethod
{
    None = 0,
    Cash = 1,
    Check = 2,
    CreditCard = 4,
    All = Cash | Check | CreditCard
 }
```

Would be a bit more clear.

Comment: It certainly is.  The only good effect of the unary is that if someone adds to the enumeration, All automagically includes it.  Still, the benefit doesn't outweigh the lack of clarity.

Comment: I don't see how that's more clear. It adds either redundancy or ambiguity: does "All" mean "exactly the set of these 3" or "everything in this enum"? If I add a new value, should I also add it to All? If I see somebody else *hasn't* added a new value to All, is that intentional? ~0 is explicit.

Comment: Personal preference aside, if the meaning of ~0 was as clear to the OP as it is to you and I, he never would have posed this question in the first place.  I'm not sure what that says about the clarity of one approach versus the other.

Comment: Since some programmers that use C# might not yet know what << means, should we code around that, too, for more clarity? I think not.

Comment: @InsidiousForce, funny story, I read an article the other day which was advocating EXACTLY that practice for exactly that reason...

Comment: @Paul, that's kind of crazy. Let's stop using ; in English because many people don't understand its use. Or all those words they don't know. Wow, such a small set of operators, and we should dumb down our code for the people that don't know what bits are and how to manipulate them?

Comment: IMO, there is a difference between "let's stop using" and "let's use a more known alternative"

Answer (score 23):

```
public enum PurchaseMethod
{   
    All = ~0, // all bits of All are 1. the ~ operator just inverts bits
    None =  0,
    Cash =  1,
    Check =  2,
    CreditCard =  4
}
```

Because of two complement in C#, `~0 == -1`, the number where all bits are 1 in the binary representation.

Comment: Looks like they are creating a bit flag for the payment method: 000 = None; 001 = Cash; 010 = Check; 100 = Credit Card; 111 = All

Comment: It's not two's complement, that's invert all the bits and add one, so that the two's complement of 0 is still 0. The ~0 simply inverts all the bits or one's complement.

Comment: No, two's complement is simply inverting all the bits.

Comment: @configurator -- that's not correct.  The ones complement is a simple inversion of bits.

Comment: c# uses two complement to represent negative values. of course ~ is not two complement, but simply inverts all bits. i'm not sure where you got that from, Beardo

Comment: Just to clarify (for my sake). This doesn't do anything special in C# since -1 != 7, so basically you will have to end up doing [All = Cash | Check | CreditCard] ?

Answer (score 17):

Its better than the

```
All = Cash | Check | CreditCard
```

solution, because if you add another method later, say:

```
PayPal = 8 ,
```

you will be already done with the tilde-All, but have to change the all-line with the other. So its less error-prone later.

regards

Comment: It's better if you also say why it's less error-prone. Like: if you store the value in a database/binary file and then add another flag to the enumeration, it'd be included in the 'All' which means that 'All' will always mean all, and not just as long as the flags are the same :).

Answer (score 11):

Just a side note, when you use

```
All = Cash | Check | CreditCard
```

you have the added  benefit that `Cash | Check | CreditCard` would evaluate to `All` and not to another value (-1) that is not equal to all while containing all values.
For example, if you use three check boxes in the UI

```
[] Cash
[] Check
[] CreditCard
```

and sum their values, and the user selects them all, you would see `All` in the resulting enum.

Comment: That's why you use `myEnum.HasFlag()` instead :D

Comment: @Pyritie: How does your comment have anything to do with what I said?

Comment: as in... if you used ~0 for "All", you could do something like `All.HasFlag(Cash | Check | CreditCard)` and that would evaulate to true. Would be a workaround since `==` doesn't always work with ~0.

Comment: Oh, I was talking about what you see in the debugger and with `ToString` - not about using `== All`.

Answer (score 9):

For others who found this question illuminating, I have a quick `~` example to share. The following snippet from the implementation of a paint method, as detailed in [this Mono documentation](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp/2.6.4-mono-.net-core/System.Windows.Forms/System/Windows/Forms/DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs.cs.htm), uses `~` to great effect:

```
PaintCells (clipBounds, 
    DataGridViewPaintParts.All & ~DataGridViewPaintParts.SelectionBackground);
```

Without the `~` operator, the code would probably look something like this:

```
PaintCells (clipBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.Background 
    | DataGridViewPaintParts.Border
    | DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentBackground
    | DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground
    | DataGridViewPaintParts.ErrorIcon
    | DataGridViewPaintParts.Focus);
```

... because the enumeration looks like this:

```
public enum DataGridViewPaintParts
{
    None = 0,
    Background = 1,
    Border = 2,
    ContentBackground = 4,
    ContentForeground = 8,
    ErrorIcon = 16,
    Focus = 32,
    SelectionBackground = 64,
    All = 127 // which is equal to Background | Border | ... | Focus
}
```

Notice this enum's similarity to Sean Bright's answer?

I think the most important take away for me is that `~` is the same operator in an enum as it is in a normal line of code.

Answer (score 5):

It's a complement operator,
Here is an article i often refer to for bitwise operators

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpLogicalBitwiseOps.aspx

Also msdn uses it in their enums article which demonstrates it use better

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The alternative I personally use, which does the same thing than @Sean Bright's answer but looks better to me, is this one:

```
[Flags]
public enum PurchaseMethod
{
    None = 0,
    Cash = 1,
    Check = 2,
    CreditCard = 4,
    PayPal = 8,
    BitCoin = 16,
    All = Cash + Check + CreditCard + PayPal + BitCoin
}
```

Notice how the binary nature of those numbers, which are all powers of two, makes the following assertion true: `(a + b + c) == (a | b | c)`. And IMHO, `+` looks better.

Answer (score 1):

I have done some experimenting with the ~ and find it that it could have pitfalls. Consider this snippet for LINQPad which shows that the All enum value does not behave as expected when all values are ored together.

```
void Main()
{
    StatusFilterEnum x = StatusFilterEnum.Standard | StatusFilterEnum.Saved;
    bool isAll = (x & StatusFilterEnum.All) == StatusFilterEnum.All;
    //isAll is false but the naive user would expect true
    isAll.Dump();
}
[Flags]
public enum StatusFilterEnum {
      Standard =0,
      Saved =1,   
      All = ~0 
}
```

Comment: Standard shouldn't get the 0 value, but something greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

Each bit in [Flags] enum means something enabled (`1`) or disabled (`0`).
`~` operator is used to invert all the bits of the number. Example: `00001001b` turns into `11110110b`.
So `~0` is used to create the value where all bits are enabled, like `11111111b` for 8-bit enum.

Just want to add that for this type of enums it may be more convenient to use bitwise left shift operator, like this:

```
[Flags]
enum SampleEnum
{
    None   = 0,      // 0000b
    First  = 1 << 0, // 0001b
    Second = 1 << 1, // 0010b
    Third  = 1 << 2, // 0100b
    Fourth = 1 << 3, // 1000b
    All    = ~0      // 1111b
}
```