# How do you return 'not uint' in C#?

Tags: c#, operators, code-conversion

I have some code written in VB that reads as follows:

```
Return (Not (crc32Result))
```

I am trying to convert it to C#, and this is what I have:

```
return (!(crc32Result));
```

However I get a compiler error:

> **Compiler Error Message:** CS0023: Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'uint'

Is there a different operator I need to be using instead of this one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like what you are trying to do is reverse the bits of crc32result.  If so, you want the tilde operator ~.

```
return (~crc32Result);
```

Reference [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387424/what-is-the-tilde-in-a-c-enumeration)

Comment: A quick explination would be helpful...in VB.NET, not can be used as a bitwise operator. In this case, it's performing negation (flipping or reversing the bits). The answer provides the C# equivilant.

Answer (score 3):

In C#, the bang(!) is used to flip a boolean variable.  Are you trying to treat the uInt above as a boolean, or perform some other reversal (reversal of all binary digits, perhaps)?

I'd suggest one of these is the solution you're looking for:

```
return (!(bool)crc32Result);  // treating as bool (0 = false, anything else is true)

return (~crc32Result); //bitwise flipping for all
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
return crc32Result == 0;
```

Or to be a little clearer on what I'm doing:

```
return !(crc32Result != 0);
```

What the second example does is convert it to boolean by the principal of "0 is false, non-zero is true".  So if it's not equal to zero, it will return true.  And then I use the '!' operator to do the "not" operation.  The Visual Basic code you gave apparently does the first part implicitly (as will C/C++), but C# and Java won't.

But this is if and ONLY if you're looking for a boolean return type from the function.  If you're doing a bit-wise inversion, then you need the following:

```
return (~crc32Result);
```

In that case, the '~' operator does the conversion to the other bit pattern.