# Operator ! can't be applied to operand ushort

Tags: c#, vb.net, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you return 'not uint' in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179574/how-do-you-return-not-uint-in-c)

Hi Everyone, I'm trying to convert the following from VB.NET to C# and I'm getting a syntax error.

VB.NET:

```
Dim CurrentCRC As UInt16
CurrentCRC = &HFFFF
CurrentCRC = Not CurrentCRC
```

C#:

```
UInt16 currentCRC = default(UInt16);
currentCRC = 0xFFFF;
currentCRC = !currentCRC;
```

The last line is giving me the syntax error of

> Operator '!' cannot be applied to
>   operand of type 'ushort'

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @charles - Yep, you're right, sorry about that.  Didn't find it when I searched :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're looking for the bitwise NOT operator (i.e. the one that flips every bit in the value), use `~`. `!` is the logical NOT operator (for boolean logic).

Answer (score 1):

`!` is the boolean `NOT` operator, i.e., it may only be applied to booleans.  If you want a bitwise `NOT` use `~`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a bitwise complement, use the [`~` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2bd4x66.aspx).

In c#, `!` is only valid for negating booleans.