# Understanding this snippet of code _num = (_num & ~(1L << 63));

Tags: c#, rngcryptoserviceprovider

Can any explain what this section of code does: `_num = (_num & ~(1L << 63));`

I've have been reading up on RNGCryptoServiceProvider and came across http://codethinktank.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/cryptographically-secure-pseudo-random.html with the code, I can follow most the code except for the section above.

I understand it ensuring that all numbers are positive, but I do not know how its doing that.

Full code

```
public static long GetInt64(bool allowNegativeValue = false)
{
    using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider _rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
         byte[] _obj = new byte[8];
         _rng.GetBytes(_obj);
         long _num = BitConverter.ToInt64(_obj, 0);
         if (!allowNegativeValue)
         {
             _num = (_num & ~(1L << 63));
         }
         return _num;
     }
}
```

Any help explaining it would be appreciated

Comment: Have a look at this post (Explaining the tidle ~ operator) and this post that explains the bitwise shift (<<) operators.

Comment: @user65439 That's better, however it's not just for my benefit. *Link only* answers are generally considered bad practice due to Link rot among other things.

Comment: Sorry the links went missing in my copy and paste above, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387424/what-is-the-tilde-in-an-enum-definition (Explaining the tidle ~ operator) and http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpShiftOperators.aspx that explains the bitwise shift (<<) operators.

Comment: Hi user65439, thanks I have bookmarked those 2 pages. The blackwasp explains bitwise shift well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<<` is the bitshift operator  `1L << 63` Results in shifting the 1 left 63 places or 1 followed by 63 `0`s

`~` is i believe bitwise not, So this would apply to the above and result in 0 followed by 63 `1`s

`&` is bitwise and, it results in applying the and operation bitwise to both operands

Ultimately this appears to be filtering it down to 63 bits of data, since any higher bits will be zeroed out due to the and

The reason this works to force positive, is because typically the highest bit(#64 in your case) is used as a sign bit in most notations, and this code just essentially `0`s it out, thus forcing it to be not negative, i.e positive

Answer (score 4):

```
a = ~(1L << 63) = ~0x1000000000000000 = 0x7fffffffffffffff
```

so `m &= a` clears the highest bit of `m`, thus ensuring it's positive, assuming the [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) encoding of signed integers is used.

Comment: And the highest bit is 1 for negative numbers in a typical representation of signed integers.

Comment: Hi Marcin thanks, on another website I was reading they had val &= 0x7fffffff; http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=775 which is just another way of writing `a = ~(1L << 63) = ~0x1000000000000000= 0x7fffffffffffffff `,

Comment: Thanks every one for the replies the help was appreciated